# What does 'should' mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

'She walked through the forest, and who should she see, but the Big Bad Wolf!'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, *should* is a way of heightening the drama of the event:

> **should** *8* used to emphasize to a listener how striking an event is or was : *you should have seen Marge's face*. [NOAD]

*Do* and *did* can be used in the same way:

> I came home early and what did I see? My wife in bed with another man!

*Should* in your sentence and *did* in mine are used as a mild form of *erotema*, a rhetorical device that asks a question to dramatize a certain event. It is, in fact, the most common device, otherwise known as a "rhetorical question".