# More on 'who should she see': what part of speech is 'should' in this phrase?

Tags: parts-of-speech

Prompted by [What does 'should' mean in this sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/17352/122), instead of asking what it means, I'm interested in what part of speech it is.

The sentence is:

> She walked through the forest, and who should she see, but the Big Bad Wolf

*Should* is being used to mean *did* in this sentence, which is an unusual use for *should*.

The general form seems to be:

> [Interrogative] should [event] but [...]

(*But* is replaceable by *except*, *only*, etc.)

Is this a subjunctive? Is it a vestige from Old English?

Comment: Is this just an alternative use/definition of the word "should"? I don't think "who should she see" and "she should see" are using the same "word" in the sense that one is a form of the other. But this isn't really my area.

Comment: I think this usage comes from the subjunctive form: "If such should happen, we would be ready."  When used in the subjunctive form, it gives the sense of chance or possibility.  So it's not far from there to use it as a helping verb that also implies that the thing happened by chance.

Comment: I don't know, but it definitely has that fairy tale feel to it.

Comment: To me it seems much more like a vestige of oral poetry and storytelling culture. The question-like phrase piques the interest of the audience but leaves no room for interruption of the narrative. It would also allow for a dramatic pause: "And *who* should she see(?)... but the big bad wolf!" The *should* may even be a reference to the story's set form - there is only one character that she's to see.

Comment: As an addendum, a similar usage can be seen in the *Odyssey*: "Then they made the ship fast a little way out, came on shore again, got their suppers, and waited till night should fall." In ordinary speech, we would obviously say "night *did* fall" or "night *fell*". Granted, this was the translator's choice, but it seems relevant that it was chosen to convey the mood of such a story.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be OED sense 17 for "shall":

> 17. In questions introduced by who, whom, what, and followed by but, serving to express the unexpectedness of some past occurrence.
>
> 1626    Bp. J. Hall Contempl. VIII. O.T. xxi. 459   Whiles his hart is taken vp with these thoughts, who should come ruffling by him, but‥Haman.
> 1832    Tennyson May Queen iv, in Poems (new ed.) 91   As I came up the valley whom think ye should I see, But Robin?
> 1842    R. Browning Pied Piper iv,   Just as he said this, what should hap At the chamber door but a gentle tap?
> 1945    R. Gibbings Lovely is Lee xxvii. 133   On the 23rd of March 1889 who should be born in Cork but myself?

Since the earliest citation is 1626, it does not seem to be a vestige from Old English.

The answer to "what is the part of speech?" is "modal".

Comment: I think that’s right. ‘Should’ is a modal verb, and it is certainly not subjunctive. As the ‘Cambridge Grammar of English’ says ‘ “Should” is also used for events which did happen but to which the speaker reacts with surprise or disbelief.’

Comment: I'm afraid I can refer you only to the book itself on Amazon: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Cambridge-Grammar-English-Paperback-Comprehensive/dp/0521674395/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1318255486&sr=1-1. (That's the UK site. It's also on the US one.)

Comment: @Barrie England : thanks for that - looks like I'll have to get an Amazon account!

Comment: I think my example from the *Odyssey* above (as a comment to the original questions) shows that *should* used in this way isn't necessarily about surprise. Sunset is about as anticipated as it gets.

Comment: onomatomaniak, your example from the Odyssey isn't the same structure as the structure in the original question. The question is about "should" used in an interrogative structure, introduced by "who, whom, what", and followed by "but".

Comment: ah, good call, morphail.

Comment: Gr8 Q, Gr8 A. And @cindi, oh to think I joined englishSE in November!

Answer (score 8):

It is used here as an auxiliary verb.

Comment: @cindi: An idea of relative ordering is not a reason for down-voting. From the faq: "As you see new answers to your question, vote up the helpful ones by clicking the upward pointing arrow to the left of the answer." If you deem this answer correct (which it is), it is therefore helpful and not worthy of a down-vote.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's an alternative use of the word "should". You might read "Who should she see but the Big Bad Wolf" as "She was surprised to see the Big Bad Wolf".

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

Here, *should* is a modal auxiliary verb.

### Explanation

English word order is normally [SVO (Subject-Verb-Object)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93object). Under some circumstances (including that phrase), the order changes to [VSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb%E2%80%93subject%E2%80%93object), in a syntactic phenomenon called [inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_%28linguistics%29). In this case, it seems to be triggered by [*wh*-movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wh-movement) of *who*, the object of *see*, to the start of the phrase.

Note that it is the subject and the auxiliary verb that get flipped; the main verb will not move. To see why, I find it simplest to [treat the auxiliary as the syntactic head](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_%28linguistics%29), and analyze the main semantic verb "see..." as the object of *should*. (Aside: this phenomenon of verb-initial word order in questions is common to many European languages. However, it is no longer productive in English, and is now used almost exclusively with auxiliary verbs!)

The original phrase is:

> who should she see but the Big Bad Wolf

Now find the underlying phrase that generates this using that [transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformational_grammar):

> *she should (see (who but the Big Bad Wolf))

Now, to determine the lexical class of *should*, let's look at the un-transformed phrase. If the ungrammaticality of the untransformed phrase bothers you, it may help to replace some of the words:

> she did (see (someone like the Big Bad Wolf))

In this case, *should* is in precisely the same lexical class as *did* would be.
Both are [auxiliary verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb). Specifically, *should* is a [modal auxiliary verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_verb), because it is used to indicate [modality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_modality).

Comment: Thanks @Mechanical snail, there are lots of interesting links for me to explore here!